# Can not load pdf with flutter package pdf_viewer_plugin

Tags: flutter

I use **flutter version 3.0.5** and **pdf_viewer_plugin: ^2.0.0** . I take pdf data from localhost asp.net 6 core web api. I have this controller:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class PdfController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoadPDF()
        {
            string path = "wwwroot/pdf/TestDoc.pdf";
            byte[] bytes= await System.IO.File.ReadAllBytesAsync(path);
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms= new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
            return new FileStreamResult(ms,"application/pdf");


        }
    }
```

When I *https://localhost:7272/api/Pdf* address in browser pdf shows, but I can not open it in flutter(android app).

Here is the flutter code:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pdf_viewer_plugin/pdf_viewer_plugin.dart';

class PdfShowPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PdfShowPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PdfShowPage> createState() => _PdfShowPageState();
}

class _PdfShowPageState extends State<PdfShowPage> {
Uint8List? list;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        //centerTitle:false,
      title: const Text('Show'),),
       body:  
       const PdfView(path: 'https://10.0.2.2:7272/api/Pdf',)
    );
  }
}
```

I also tried with test pdf page on web *https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf* , but I again got same error :

```
I/PdfViewer(11197): onDetachedFromWindow
Restarted application in 2,061ms.
E/FrameEvents(11197): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(11197): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/PDFView (11197): load pdf error
E/PDFView (11197): java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
E/PDFView (11197):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:344)
E/PDFView (11197):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:231)
E/PDFView (11197):  at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.source.FileSource.createDocument(FileSource.java:37)
E/PDFView (11197):  at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:49)
E/PDFView (11197):  at com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.DecodingAsyncTask.doInBackground(DecodingAsyncTask.java:25)
E/PDFView (11197):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
E/PDFView (11197):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
E/PDFView (11197):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
E/PDFView (11197):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
E/PDFView (11197):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
E/FrameEvents(11197): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
E/FrameEvents(11197): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
```

Comment: Have you added the internet permission in android manifest file?

Comment: I didn't. But now after I have added it, it still doesn't work.